# How to allow users to send emails to other users in Parse app?

Tags: swift, email, parse-platform, messaging

Initially planned on adding a direct messaging function in my app. But since I do not have time to learn and implement that function right now, I decided to just allow users to send emails to one another for contact.

I have been trying to search for tutorials, but most were for confirmation emails, etc.

Could anyone point me in the right direction, to learn to implement this function?

Thanx.

Comment: Uhmm... mailto links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by looking into "[MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/)".

This class provides a standard interface that manages the editing and sending of email messages. Quite simple. With a couple of lines of code you can present your users with a friendly editor to write and send emails.